# How to get the whole string into the input type text

Tags: php, string, input, text, types

```
        <?php               
        echo "<tr>";
        echo $dna;
        echo "<td width='120' class='textfett'>Deutscher Name</td>";
        echo "<td width='114' class='titel'><input type='text' name='dname' value=$dna   size='50' maxlength='50'></td>";
       echo "<tr>";
       ?>
```

if $dna is two words, only one, the first, will be used as value.

Comment: Use quote marks round the value, like all your other attributes. `value='$dna'`.

Comment: Ps. You should not be echoing anything in the table which is outside a td or th. Echoing $dna directly into the tr isn't valid, not sure why you've done that

Comment: Additionally you should escape the `$dna` value and other variables, to ensure other quotes and element tags in the variable do not break the HTML. Especially when using variables in html attributes. `<input type='text' name='dname' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($dna, ENT_QUOTES); ?>'   size='50' maxlength='50'>`

Answer (score 1):

You are essentually outputting a single value in a chunk of HTML, so instead of doing

```
<?php               
        echo "<tr>";
        echo $dna;
        echo "<td width='120' class='textfett'>Deutscher Name</td>";
        echo "<td width='114' class='titel'><input type='text' name='dname' value=$dna   size='50' maxlength='50'></td>";
       echo "<tr>";
       ?>
```

Do this

```
<tr>
    <td width="120" class="textfett">Deutscher Name</td>
    <td width="114" class="titel">
       <input type="text" name="dname" value="<?= htmlentities($dna) ?>" size="50" maxlength="50">
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can break out of PHP or not use it at all, you don't need to echo every line you output.